# no such file or directory found error while creating a docker image

Tags: docker, deployment, docker-container, docker-image

I want to creat or build a docker image using the command below:

```
docker build -t project/test:v1 .
```

I have a Dockerfile in which one command is failing as such:

```
Step 9/13 : COPY --from=ams-fe /fecode/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/16fd63a9ce16d7d132ab6bb9c768c76c5670c9fe60a6e06440607ac6e6af911c/merged/fecode/dist: no such file or directory
```

Can anyone help what is the issue with this command as I am using it for `Nginx based web server` ?

Below image shows the error in this regard.

[image: docker image error]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see two different things:

1. **JavaScript heap out of memory**

Try launching docker container with more memory reservation, checking previously that you don't exceed kernel available memory.

```
cat /proc/meminfo
```

With this data, do:

```
docker run --memory-reservation=XXX --kernel-memory=XXX ...
```

More information in [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#specify-an-init-process)

2. **COPY failed**

You're building docker executing `docker build` in a directory which doesn't have path to `/fecode/dist`
Note that Dockerfile checks locally existence of files to copy.